# How to determine the Stack space after overwriting the EIP

Tags: security, assembly, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am learning Stack Based Buffer overflow on the x86 Linux.
How to count the size of the stack space after overwriting the EIP in GDB with some value?

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x1  1
ecx            0xffffd7a0   -10336
edx            0xffffd17b   -11909
ebx            0xff5f8948   -10516152
esp            0xffffd180   0xffffd180
ebp            0x80ad26dc   0x80ad26dc
esi            0xf7fc2000   -134471680
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x66666666   0x66666666
eflags         0x10282  [ SF IF RF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x63 99


(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffd184:
 eip = 0x66666666; saved eip = 0xffffd300
 called by frame at 0x80ad26e4
 Arglist at 0xffffd17c, args: 
 Locals at 0xffffd17c, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffd184
 Saved registers:
  eip at 0xffffd180


(gdb) info stack
#0  0x66666666 in ?? ()
#1  0xffffd300 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

EDIT: Thanks for the answers, the exact command in GDB giving the right answer for this question is `info proc`

(gdb) info proc all

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the stack itself — the memory of the stack.  Try decoding the stack yourself, maybe start with something like `x/20x $esp` to dump the stack.

For one, you're looking for the return address stored in the stack: if you put a breakpoint on the first instruction of the function, then the return address is the top thing on the stack.  So, print the stack before executing a single instruction of the function, and that will tell you both the stack location and the value of the return address on the stack.

As you run the initial part of the function, it will allocate stack space for the buffer (assuming it is a local array variable).

Then, you want to see where the buffer is located with that stack space.  You can do this a number of ways — run the code and see where your input string winds up using the same command to dump the stack immediately after the input operation — or, disassemble the code and see what stack address it passes to `gets` or `scanf`, either approach should tell you where the buffer starts (and you can do both approaches to validate the other).

Once you know where the buffer starts and where the return address is stored, you can tell how many character (bytes) of input it will take to overwrite the return address.